# Combining multiple columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 40 columns (columns 0 through 39) and I want to group them four at a time:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, (100, 40)))
```

---

```
new_df["0-3"] = df[0] + df[1] + df[2] + df[3]
new_df["4-7"] = df[4] + df[5] + df[6] + df[7]
...
new_df["36-39"] = df[36] + df[37] + df[38] + df[39]
```

Can I do this in a single statement (or in a better way than summing them separately)? The column names in the new DataFrame are not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way to go but I ended up using MultiIndex:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((range(10), range(4)))
new_df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

Update: Probably because of the index, this was faster than the alternatives. The same can be done with `df.groupby(df.columns//4, axis=1).sum()` faster if you take into account the time for constructing the index. However, the index change is a one time operation and I update the df and take the sum thousands of times so using a MultiIndex was faster for me.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970526/need-help-to-solve-the-unnamed-and-to-change-it-in-dataframe-in-pandas/49970566#comment86991353_49970566

Answer (score 2):

You could select out the columns and sum on the row axis, like this.

```
df['0-3'] = df.loc[:, 0:3].sum(axis=1)
```

A couple things to note:

1. Summing like this will ignore missing data while `df[0] + df[1] ...` propagates it. Pass `skipna=False` if you want that behavior.
2. Not necessarily any performance benefit, may actually be a little slower.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```
new_df = df.transpose()  
new_df['Group'] = new_df.index / 4  
new_df = new_df.groupby('Group').sum().transpose()
```

Note that the divide-by operation here is [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), not floating-point division.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a list comprehension:

```
df = # your data
df_slices = [df.iloc[x:x+4] for x in range(10)]
```

Or more generally

```
df_slices = [df.iloc[x:x+4] for x in range(len(df.columns)/4)]
```